# Invalid or illegal string exception when Web Audio API audio context is created

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm working on my personal website with vanilla javascript HTML and CSS to fill some holes I've got regarding tags and styling to name a few. Right now I'm trying to add some cool sound design to it with the Web Audio API but I'm not able to create an audio context. On Firefox my console reports the following:

> Uncaught DOMException: An invalid or illegal string was specified

I've run the website on Edge as well, it doesn't throw the same exception though but same luck, I can't create an audio context. I've also removed `defer` from my `<script>` tag to check if my issue comes down to execution order but again I'm no able to create the audio context.

My last try was to simulate the issue with another project that scoped the problem and I couldn't get any better result or a clue that pointed me what I did wrong.

There's not much code to share because this is step one for my sound design implementation stage. I've got this so far:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>        
  <html lang="en-US">                                                                                
    <head>                                                                                          
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>       
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>                                               <title>Waves in a room portfolio</title>                                                      
      <script src="interaction.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>                     
     </head>
  </html>
```

*interaction.js*

```
const audioCtxt = new AudioContext();

const navButtons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(`panel-button`));
const dropDownMenuButton = document.querySelector(`#dropdown-menu>button`);
const skillsButtons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(`skill-button`));
const skillsArticles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`#skills>section:nth-of-type(2)>article`));
const windows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.window`));


dropDownMenuButton.addEventListener(`click`, ()=>{
  dropDownMenuButton.classList.add(`active`);
  document.querySelector(`#dropdown-menu>menu`).style.display = `block`;
})


navButtons.forEach((button)=>{
  button.addEventListener(`click`, ()=>{
    document.getElementById(button.dataset.panel).scrollIntoView({behavior:`smooth`, block: `center`});
  })
})

skillsButtons.forEach((skill)=>{
  skill.addEventListener(`click`, ()=>{
    for(const button of skillsButtons){
      if(skill.dataset.skill === button.dataset.skill){
        button.classList.add(`selected`);
        document.getElementById(button.dataset.skill).style.display = `block`;
      }else{
        button.classList.remove(`selected`);
        document.getElementById(button.dataset.skill).style.display = `none`;
      }
    }
  })
})

windows.forEach((panel)=>{
  panel.addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=>{
    panel.style.opacity = `1`;
    panel.style.boxShadow = `8px 8px var(--gray-100)`;
    panel.children[0].style.backgroundColor = `var(--orange-100)`;
    panel.children[0].style.color = 'var(--black-200)';
  })
})

windows.forEach((panel)=>{
  panel.addEventListener(`mouseleave`, ()=>{
    panel.style.opacity = `0.5`;
    panel.children[0].style.backgroundColor = `var(--black-200)`;
    panel.style.boxShadow = `none`;
    panel.children[0].style.color = `var(--white-100)`;
  })
})

document.addEventListener(`click`, (e)=>{
  if(!e.target.closest(`#dropdown-menu>button`)){
    dropDownMenuButton.classList.remove(`active`);
    document.querySelector(`#dropdown-menu>menu`).style.display = `none`;
  }

  if(!e.target.closest(`#skills>section`)&&!e.target.closest(`#skills>h4`)){
    const selectedSkillButton = document.querySelector(`.selected`)
    if(selectedSkillButton){
      selectedSkillButton.classList.remove(`selected`);
      document.getElementById(selectedSkillButton.dataset.skill).style.display = `none`;
    }
  }
})
```

[image: Firefox exception]

What baffles me is a previous project I worked on with React.js didn't have the same problem. Is there anything with vanilla Javascript/HTML/CSS that I should be aware of? Could you point out what I'm missing please?

BTW CSS works perfectly and some non audio related interaction inside the interaction file runs smoothly. Adding the line that creates the `AudioContext` is causing the issue. Also, adding `const audioCtxt = new AudioContext();` inside `<script>` tag in `index.html` doesn't throw the exception.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. If you want help with your code, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't show the code you want help with. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/77360931/edit) and add some code to your question. Right now running the code you have posted does not reproduce the error you mentioned.

Comment: Sure @ChrisBarr, thanks for your feedback. I'm gonna pull up something to help other see what I'm dealing with and edit the description.

Comment: I see you've added some HTML that shows a link to a file we do not have access to.  I imagine the code you want help with is in that file.  Just post the  JScode, no need to show the standard way to link to JS files in your HTML, you don't have a problem with that and that has been standard for 20+ years. Edit your question and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question. When you add it, please be sure that it properly demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Just added the entire code inside *interaction.js* plus a screenshot of the exception. Tested that the code threw the exception on my side as well. The HTML file is huge and I don't feel it contributes to the description of the problem.

Comment: That helps, but in general this issue you have is still not **reproducible** since the JS needs some related HTML to function at all.  The goal for a stack overflow question is to make the issue **minimal** (meaning: do not post a huge HTML file, but enough to make things work) and **reproducible** (meaning: anyone reading your question should be able to make your problem happen - if they can do that there's a chance they can suggest a fix).  In your code you create `audioCtxt` but it's never used anywhere. Isn't your question about an error from using this?

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean Chris, those are valid pointers. I cloned the project on my laptop and same issue then I asked somebody from *The Audio Programmer* community to clone and test the repo on his side and he told me he didn't get any errors. I use WSL2 Ubuntu for coding so I copied the project folder on windows and nothing. Thought that my code had something strange but there was nothing wrong with it. I'll detail my question next time more and describe what I've tried better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... it turns out that the problem was caused by one of my browser extensions I work with to visualize Web Audio API connected nodes. I've already helped the team with sending an issue on Github and the lesson I take from this but is to consider browser extensions as the source of a bug.